# Docusign- How to handle if our client has SSO enabled for DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

My company has DocuSign enabled and we use RESTAPI oAuth to create and send envelopes.
One of our clients said they have SSO enabled in their org and would like to SSO directly to DocuSign from my page. In our current implementation, users are prompted for email address first and then the password.
Any help in this area is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Login UI from DocuSign indeed first prompts for email address.
The magic happens at that point.
If the domain of the email (in my case inbar.gazit@docusign.com -> docusign.com) is registered with DocuSign as SSO, DocuSign would give you the option at that point to **USE COMPANY LOGIN** and then when you click that, the IDP (Identity Provider) would take over and enable the end-user to login with SSO without having to provide a password.
Try it - it works.
[image]

Comment: Thank you Inbar.  Does my company (companyA) have to do anything from obtaining consent for our ClientA (who has SSO enabled) . We are using oAuth calls for API calls

Comment: if I answered your question - would you mind marking this as answered? if you have additional questions - please post them separately .

Comment: its sort of answered.I can open a new ticket for the above comment